# Custom cursor starts in top left of page when page reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using a custom cursor which is working fine, but when the page loads the custom mouse cursor starts in the top left corner until the user moves the mouse and then it jumps to where it iss supposed to be. How can I make it start where the cursor actually is? Code snippet and Codepen below. Thanks in advance!

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gwjr/pen/KKRxjdg)

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
let Links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
let logo = document.querySelector(".logo-error");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cursor);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);

function cursor(e){

    mouseCursor.style.top = "calc(" +e.pageY + "px - 1rem)";
    mouseCursor.style.left = "calc(" +e.pageX + "px - 1rem)";
}

Links.forEach(link =>{

    if ( link !== logo ){

        link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {

            mouseCursor.classList.remove("link-grow");
        });

        link.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {

            mouseCursor.classList.add("link-grow");
        });
    }  

});

iframes.forEach(frame =>{
  
      
        frame.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    
            mouseCursor.classList.remove("hide");
        });
  
        frame.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    
            mouseCursor.classList.add("hide");
        });
    
});
```

```css
body{
    cursor: none;
  
}

.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a{
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.cursor{
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition-property: background, transform;
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: 20000;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.link-grow{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    cursor: none;
}

.logo-error:hover .cursor{
    display: none !important;
}
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `#cursor` element appear/disappear when the real cursor enters/leaves the window, add some `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` event  handlers to the document which hide/show `#cursor`. It would also be a good idea to have the initial state of `#cursor` set to `display: none` in CSS.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'block');
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'none');
```

Here's a working example:

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
let Links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
let logo = document.querySelector(".logo-error");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cursor);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'block');
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'none');

function cursor(e) {
  mouseCursor.style.top = "calc(" + e.pageY + "px - 1rem)";
  mouseCursor.style.left = "calc(" + e.pageX + "px - 1rem)";
}

Links.forEach(link => {
  if (link !== logo) {
    link.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      mouseCursor.classList.remove("link-grow");
    });
    
    link.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      mouseCursor.classList.add("link-grow");
    });
  }
});

iframes.forEach(frame => {
  frame.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    mouseCursor.classList.remove("hide");
  });
  
  frame.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    mouseCursor.classList.add("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.cursor {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition-property: background, transform;
  transform-origin: center center;
  z-index: 20000;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}

.link-grow {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
  cursor: none;
}

.logo-error:hover .cursor {
  display: none !important;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that positions the custom cursor only runs on mousemove, you need to run it on load as well, like so:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cursor);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, I've update the code above and you can see it still loads top left.

Comment: Is there an easy way to hide the cursor until its moved?